# Edittext control cursor location

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I want to control editText's cursor position. I have a textwatcher associated with it. In the editText the text is a formatted string. what i want is while adding i want to keep the cursor at the end and while deleting i want to keep the cursor on where its deleting. I am trying like this.

My problem is while adding text its cursor location is not at the end rather its in the beginning of the text and while removing though sometimes it can put its cursor location at the desired place it gets index out of bound exception sometimes.

```
@Override
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    formattedString = s.toString();
    if (before > count) {
      if (!formattedString.contains(",") && formattedString.length() > 4) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(s);
        stringBuilder.deleteCharAt(s.length() - 4);
        formattedString = stringBuilder.toString();
      }
    } else {
      EditText editText = editTextWeakReference.get();
      editText.setSelection(0);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
    EditText editText = editTextWeakReference.get();
    if (editText == null) {
      return;
    }

    cursorPosition = editText.getSelectionEnd();
    editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);
    String cleanString = formattedString.toString().replaceAll("[￥,]", "");

    if (cleanString.contains(".")) {
      int dotPosition = cleanString.indexOf(".");
      if (dotPosition == 6) {
        cleanString = cleanString.substring(0, 6);
      }
    }
    if (!cleanString.equals("")) {

      if (!cleanString.contains(".")
          && cleanString.length() > 6) {
        cleanString = cleanString.substring(0, cleanString.length() - 1);
      }
    }
    String formatted = "";
    if (!cleanString.equals("")) {
      formatted = CurrencyUtil.getCurrency(cleanString);
    }
    editText.setText(formatted);
    if (cursorPosition != 1) {
      editText.setSelection(cursorPosition);
    }

    editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
  }
```

Comment: `am trying like this` and the problem is <enter your problem here>. And my question is <enter your question here>.

Comment: updated my question. please check